# Guarantees of data preservation between int32_t and float?

Tags: c, arduino, avr-gcc

I'm reading through the supplied code for a demo board(specifically the DC21561A) and found this snippet of code:

```
int32_t min_current_threshold_code;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
min_current_threshold_code = (min_current_threshold / LTC2946_DELTA_SENSE_lsb) * resistor;                                                                                                                                                   
ack |= LTC2946_write_16_bits(LTC2946_I2C_ADDRESS, LTC2946_MIN_DELTA_SENSE_THRESHOLD_MSB_REG, (min_current_threshold_code << 4));
```

Here, everything on the RHS of first assignment is a float. From what I can tell, and have tested, an assignment with LHS int32_t and RHS float the decimal bits of the float will be discarded and only the integer is left; i.e. '1.5 * 3.5 = 5'.

The data above is written to a register over I2C. I assume the floats are used to give a more accurate estimate of threshold values. However, I was wondering if this truncation when assigning a float to an int32_t is required by the C(or C++) standard or something compiler specific?

Edit** Some people have asked for more code. While my question is answered, here's the rest for thoroughness.

At the top of the file there is

> float min_current_threshold = read_float();
>
> const float LTC2946_DELTA_SENSE_lsb = 2.5006105E-05;
>
> const float resistor = .02;

Comment: Does it make sense to shift the integer value left 4 times *after* truncating any fractional part? Or is that to align with a bit-field?

Comment: @WeatherVane I did not actually write that code. This is vendor supplied, so I'm assuming it's correct(this bit is also useless to me so I don't really care). I was more curious what the standard guarantees.

Comment: Aside: code should round after scaling as with `min_current_threshold_code = lroundf(min_current_threshold / LTC2946_DELTA_SENSE_lsb * resistor * 16);` rather than truncate and then scale.

Comment: @chux I agree with this. The vendor codebase this is a part of has a few other things I think are wonky, but, I'll be rewriting most of this so I guess we'll see...

Comment: I see no `float` in your sample code... Please, can you edit your question and specify in what part of your code a `float` number if being handled? If so, what format is used to store it? can you describe? Thanks (all the multiplications, divisions and shifts are made over 32 bit integer values, no floating point arithmetic involved in that code)

Comment: Can you post a verifiable piece of code where we can see how each variable is defined?  THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the standards mandates the truncation, for example in C99 chapter 6.3.1.4 paragraph 1:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than **_Bool**, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero).

Answer (score 2):

6.3.1.4 states:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer
>   type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the
>   value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
>   cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.
>   61)

And then there is a non-normative foot note explaining the above text:

> 61) The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type
>   is converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of
>   real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of
>   portable real floating values is (−1, Utype_MAX+1).